# Help with formula field needed

Tags: formula-field, relationships, update

The population of ABC fields depends on **field__r.Account__r.Name** field.

I want to assigned **ABC** formula field with **field__r.Account__r.Name** value if **field__r.field__c** is blank,

but if there are some values in **field__r.field__c** then **ABC** field should be **OpportunityName__r.Account.Name** value

So I tried this...

```
IF(ISBLANK(field__r.field__c), OpportunityName__r.Account.Name, field__r.Account__r.Name)
```

Is it achievable using formula fields? thanks

Comment: Hi, you need to provide some more details like.. in which object you are creating this formula field ? how is this object related to opportunity or account object ? is field__c a custom lookup field in your object & why are you using Account__r & OpportunityName__r ? and finally it seems there's nothing with validation rule i believe.. can u change your question title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you now have it inverse to how you want it.

Fix it like

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(field__r.field__c)), OpportunityName__r.Account.Name, field__r.Account__r.Name)
```

or

```
IF(ISBLANK(field__r.field__c), field__r.Account__r.Name, OpportunityName__r.Account.Name)
```

Comment: IF(ISBLANK(exp),a,b) seemed to be ok. I messed up with the fields. I appreciate your help. Thanks